# adding color when drawing fractals in haskell

Tags: haskell, colors

Hi we are trying to make the code use a color when drawing the fractals.
We are using graphics.HGL package. We are able use use a specific color, but only when putting it in our self with the function withColor. In this case we use the color green.
We want it to be able process from the fractal to the commands, so it can change color without interfering with our basic code. Any suggestions to how we can make this work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to retain the current separation of concerns, you could add a color field to the `Forward` command (perhaps also the `Backward` command?). Like this:

```
data Command = Forward Color | Backward Color | {- remaining constructors are unchanged -}
```

Then your drawing function will know which color to use during its draw calls. Of course, you will have to change your `Fractal -> [Command]` function to choose colors when needed!